# What makes common matter what it is compared to, for example, Electromagnetic Fields?

Tags: particle-physics, mass, fermions, bosons

Last week, I discussed with some friends (we are all Physics Students) what are the differences between photons and electrons that account for the differences between light and matter. One team argued that the most important was mass because without mass matter could never be at rest. The other team argued that the most important thing was to be fermionic because

1) if things can ocuppy the same state you clearly can't identify them as macroscopic matter

2) because we can't simply go trhough matter "without touching it" and this is related to fermionic statistics. I think that these ideas are all reasonable and would like to hear some answers of people with far more knowledge about particle physics that I have.

One other thing that I should address is that in the discussion it was said that if only mass is important then massive gauge bosons such as gluons or W and Z bosons should form some kind of matter -which of course they don't.

Comment: In a nutshell both are correct. However, fermions hold together using virtual bosons. So it probably is better to say that ordinary matter consists of fermions held together by virtual bosons. For example, 99% of the mass of everything around us is the energy of virtual massless gluons holding quarks together inside nucleons. Gluons are bosons, so 99% of our mass comes from virtual bosons inside us. Add to this that "virtual" means they don't exist, but represent quantum fields, and you'll have even more confusion.

Comment: You should start by asking: What's the most important difference between light and matter? This is a subjective question, and depending on what answer you decide to use, different properties become important.

Anyway, the team arguing that the reason you can't go through matter because it's fermionic is wrong in practically every normal situation (with the exception of the cores of stars, the beginning of the universe and Bose-Einstein condensates). You can't go through matter because you interact with it electrostatically. If photons were charged, you couldn't go through them either.

Comment: (Also, if photons were charged, a lot of other things would be so different that normal matter probably couldn't exist. So if it were me, I would probably say that electric charge is what distinguishes them.)

Answer (score 1):

Common matter and radiations  , are very well modeled using the [standard model of particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) physics. It is a complex mathematical model that cannot be summarized with binary statements: it needs the group algebra of SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) , which can be visualized but cannot be said to be "this or the other", and the panoply of quantum field theory to model any measurements.

> differences between photons and electrons

It is not just that photons are massless with spin 1 and electrons massive with spin 1/2 but the whole concept of the group symmetries is needed to identify them . They belong to different niches of these symmetries.

A gross divide between radiation and matter comes from the impossibility of radiation to form stable bound states, whereas matter forms bound states. This is mathematically modeled using the framework of quantum mechanics and quantum field theory. In this successful model, radiation is a basic carrier of the forces that bind together particles, [the column on the right in the link.](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html)